# Grab post id from WooCommerce my-orders.php template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I grab the post id from the WooCommerce my-orders.php file? 
Currently there is a list of orders placed when viewing this page, but I need to modify it so that I can echo the post id of the product purchased, currently only the order id is showing.

Thanks

```
<?php
/**
 * My Orders
 *
 * Shows recent orders on the account page
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.3.10
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) ) );

if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', __( 'Recent Orders', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></h2>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="order-number"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-date"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-status"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-total"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-actions">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody><?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
                $order->populate( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();

                ?><tr class="order">
                    <td class="order-number" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Order Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                            <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-date" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-status" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;">
                        <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-total" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-actions">
                        <?php
                            $actions = array();

                            if ( $order->needs_payment() ) {
                                $actions['pay'] = array(
                                    'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                    'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' )
                                );
                            }

                            if ( in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                $actions['cancel'] = array(
                                    'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                    'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
                                );
                            }

                            $actions['view'] = array(
                                'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' )
                            );

                            $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order );

                            if ( $actions ) {
                                foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr><?php
            }
        ?></tbody>

    </table>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: please update your question with  the full php code of my-order.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example this might help you but it depend on you `my-order.php` template but your theme maybe already have the code I have added bellow

```
<?php
/**
 * My Orders
 *
 * Shows recent orders on the account page
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.3.10
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) ) );

if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', __( 'Recent Orders', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></h2>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="order-number"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-number"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Product ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-date"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-status"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-total"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-actions">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody><?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
                $order->populate( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
                $_product_id = $order->product_id();

                ?><tr class="order">
                    <td class="order-number" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Order Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                            <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-number" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <a href="<?php get_post_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php echo _x( 'Product ID # ', 'hash before product ID', 'woocommerce' ) . $_product_id; ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-date" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-status" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;">
                        <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-total" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-actions">
                        <?php
                            $actions = array();

                            if ( $order->needs_payment() ) {
                                $actions['pay'] = array(
                                    'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                    'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' )
                                );
                            }

                            if ( in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                $actions['cancel'] = array(
                                    'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                    'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
                                );
                            }

                            $actions['view'] = array(
                                'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' )
                            );

                            $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order );

                            if ( $actions ) {
                                foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr><?php
            }
        ?></tbody>

    </table>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't produce the product id I'm afraid. I have the default my-orders.php file from the latest WooCommerce installation.

Comment: @HuwRowlands I have updated my answer please copy full code and replace with your code

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with:

```
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach( $items as $item) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        }
```